# How to get all childs data on ListView - Firebase database

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: image description here]

i need to get all data in Childs and show it in  ListView

Every Values in Childs!,The main Child is "XXX-Users" and other Childs is about "Model Phones",, i want get All Date of This Childs on ListView

this is my Activity:

```
public class xxxxxxx extends AppCompatActivity {ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>() ;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("xxx-Users");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxxxxxxxxxxxx);





    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview00);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,usernames);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String  value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            usernames.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

}`**

**My Layout**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview00" />
```

Comment: Please look at the FirebaseUi library

Comment: Is your code working, though? `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` does not look correct compared to your data... Also, you should input code into `onCancelled` to tell you your errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cricket_007 said, your code doesn't match your data structure. Your listener will fire for the nodes immediately under `xxx-Users`. But your actual URL values are one level deeper.

One simple way to handler this is to loop over those nested children in `onChildAdded()`:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("xxx-Users");
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
      for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String  value = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        usernames.add(value);
      }
      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: "Users" is a bit misleading as a key name. Those look like groups, maybe, if each child is a user string